# SQL Server: optimal indexing strategies for many-to-many join

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-indexes

Let's say I have two tables, `items` and `stores`, with primary keys `item_id` and `store_id` respectively.  Since there is a many-to-many relation here, I also have an intermediate table, `items_stores`, with both `item_id` and `store_id` columns.  Thus, I can carry out my two main kinds of queries: (A) find all the items in a store, and (B) find all the stores that have an item.

So far, so good.  Now I would like to put one or more indexes on `items_stores` to speed up my queries.  Given these kinds of queries, should I create two separate single-column indexes (`item_id` and `store_id`), or one or more multi-column indexes?  I say more because I know that the columns in a SQL server index are accessed left-to-right, so there could potentially be both `<item_id, store_id>` and `<store_id, item_id>`.

Comment: I could give you a fish, but you should learn fishing. Check this: MySQL index [**TIPS**](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: Do you consider any of your queries to be more often used than others? Or the order of importance in regards to required performance improvement? Usually in these situations I go with either (A,B) + (B) or (B,A) + (A) but that entirely depends on what it's like for you

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza That link is for MySQL and this question is tagged Sql-Server.

Comment: Essentially, it entirely depends on what the data looks like and what queries you're going to be running. For example... Are `store_id, item_id` combinations unique (e.g. each store can only have one of each item_id) or is there some other unique combination in that table? Is store_id more selective than item_id?  Would you be running more queries to find which items are in a store or which stores have an item (or are both about the same)?

Comment: @SqlZim Index techniques are almost the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're new to indexing (heck even if you're not) I would just run the estimated execution plan on your common queries and create the suggested indexes. Keep an eye on the disk space and your data insert/update performance.

I tend to do this with all new queries, running the execution plan several times with slight code variations to find the right balance between query performance and insert/update speed.

Couple this with a bit of reading and you will get the hang of it pretty quickly and start to think about optimizing.

You also need to think about fragmentation and rebuilding indexes. This can be automated with T-SQL stored procedures so you can mostly set and forget it.

Here are some useful links:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/?article=610

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/14-sql-server-indexing-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes#TsqlProcedureFrag